# What are the advantages of creating a dapp over a normal web application?

Tags: dapps

A lot of dapps seem like nothing new to me and the added benefit of creating a dapp seems very minimal besides decentralization.

Comment: Anyone can help me understand the following line. "without trusted intermediaries" I have tried researching a lot how intermediaries will avoid, but I did not get a complete answer from anybody. Someone help me with an example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23427)

Answer (score 7):

Making an Ethereum-backed web application gives you several things for free:

- **Payment processing**: No need to integrate with Stripe or PayPal to accept funds from users. All users can send/receive Ether as a common payment means.
- **User Credentials**: Users don't need to sign up; they already have an account, which is a public/private key to bind with their user session and metadata.
- **Database**: Storing a lot of data in the blockchain is expensive, so likely the blockchain isn't going to be the *only* database for the application, but mission-critical pieces of data can be stored forever on the blockchain.
- **Logging**: Etherum contracts can create their own logs, which a DApp can query to know what's happened in the past, rather than needing to create separate logs.
- **Trust**: Your users can trust your code, since not only is the front-end (Javascript) code visible (via browser inspection tools), but the back-end logic (contract code) can be inspected too, so it can be independently verified that your code doesn't have backdoors in it to steal all their funds.

If you're planning on using any of these in your application, either initially or long-term, building as Ethereum-backed (a DApp) gives it a nice head-start.

Answer (score 0):

Decentralized app (DApp) is an app either mobile or web which interacts with a smart contract.
The main benefit is to have a decentralized protocol as a backend to operate with stored value:

- without trusted intermediaries
- on predefined terms
- in deterministic manner

Check out State of dapps for inspirations https://dapps.ethercasts.com

The most important type of dApp is a crowd sale web app for ICO using ECR20 tokens

Comment: I agree with most of that, except for your last line. Recently the most _popular_ uses for DApps are for ICO sales, but that does not make them the most _important_.

Comment: @MidnightLightning thank you, so which dapps are most important ?

Comment: It depends on who's asking. To someone making their livelihood on [Ethlance](https://ethlance.com/), that's is most important. To someone participating in a [ROSCA](https://rosca.wetrust.io/tutorial) because they can't get insurance another way, that's most important. To a business spending lots of money advertising a .ETH domain, the [ENS](https://ens.domains/) contract is most important. _Important_ is completely subjective, and Ethereum encourages all sorts of niches that are important to different sorts of people to co-exist, which is great!

Comment: Great comment @MidnightLighting . What is Important for you?

Comment: Personally, I'll root for the DApps supporting large, complex contracts to continue to be developed (e.g. https://registrar.ens.domains/), as I believe those apps are the ones where the developer community learns the most, and helps shape the future of the whole Ethereum ecosystem. But this sort of discussion's best left for another forum, rather than a Q&A site.