# Can one decentralize an existing app already using paypal as payment?

Tags: solidity, tokens, dapp-development, erc-20

I am looking at decentralizing an existing app to a dapp using ethereum smart contact. the app uses Paypal for membership, advertising and affiliate payment  already but i dont want to use Paypal, I need an ERC20 Token as Payment.

I will need help to moveforward

thanks

Comment: There are decentralized apps that uses tokens/ether as payment method. You say not much about your application, besides that it uses paypal, so we cannot say how feasible is the switch to ether/tokens. Perhaps you should take a look at something like Coinbase Commerce.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! But you have to understand that Ethereum DApps have a lot of limitations and there are a lot of different problems you need to consider. If you go the in-browser route, you need to start writing towards [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) and your customers will need to use [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) to interact with your application. This assumes you want to use ether.

But you said you wanted to use an ERC20 token as a payment. Do you mean an existing ERC20 token (e.g., EOS, FUN, SALT, some other token), or do you want to create your own token? If you create your own token, are you doing so because your application actually has a monetary transactable value, or do you just want to be able to claim you're using your own token?

The thing is, ERC20 tokens are harder to accept than traditional ether. Metamask doesn't provide a way to send tokens out of the box. If you want to receive an existing token, you need to come up with a way for people to transact tokens with Metamask, then interact with your application. That's a lot of work.

You could also build a DApp on something like [Parity](https://paritytech.github.io/wiki/). The only problem with this approach is that if you do that, you might limit your customer base. It would probably be easier to interact with tokens, but it requires a separate download and chain sync.

These resources might help you:

- [What are the advantages of creating a dapp over a normal web application?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17284/what-are-the-advantages-of-creating-a-dapp-over-a-normal-web-application)
- [Ethereum for web developers](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/ethereum-for-web-developers-890be23d1d0c)
- [Accepting an ERC20 Token as Payment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23567/accepting-an-erc20-token-as-payment)
- [Ethereum smart service payment with tokens](https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/ethereum-smart-service-payment-with-tokens-60894a79f75c)